Downloaded .movpkg not playing until connected with network
I downloaded a few HLS streaming videos as .movpkg folders. I turned off both wifi and LTE. Some of the videos are playing and some are not. I checked the file size and those not playing are obviously too small compared with those playing. So obviously they are not really downloaded. Then I connected with wifi and the 'bad' .movpkg are now playing (and downloading many .frag files - OpenGL Shading Language Fragment Shader). I use AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask.
So why those video were not fully downloaded? The HLS should be FairPlay.
Update: Adding code for downloading
func downloadStream(for asset: Asset) {
        // Get the default media selections for the asset's media selection groups.
        let preferredMediaSelection = asset.urlAsset.preferredMediaSelection
        /*
         Creates and initializes an AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask to download multiple AVMediaSelections
         on an AVURLAsset.
         
         For the initial download, we ask the URLSession for an AVAssetDownloadTask with a minimum bitrate
         corresponding with one of the lower bitrate variants in the asset.
         */
        guard let task =
                assetDownloadURLSession.aggregateAssetDownloadTask(with: asset.urlAsset,
                                                                   mediaSelections: [preferredMediaSelection],
                                                                   assetTitle: asset.stream.name,
                                                                   assetArtworkData: nil,
                                                                   options:
                                                                    [AVAssetDownloadTaskMinimumRequiredMediaBitrateKey: 265_000]) else { return }
        // To better track the AVAssetDownloadTask, set the taskDescription to something unique for the sample.
        task.taskDescription = asset.stream.name
        activeDownloadsMap[task] = asset
        task.resume()
        var userInfo = [String: Any]()
        userInfo[Asset.Keys.name] = asset.stream.name
        userInfo[Asset.Keys.downloadState] = Asset.DownloadState.downloading.rawValue
        userInfo[Asset.Keys.downloadSelectionDisplayName] = displayNamesForSelectedMediaOptions(preferredMediaSelection)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .AssetDownloadStateChanged, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    }


You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. Show your code for downloading and playing the videos specifically.

@DavidPasztorThanks for reminding. Just added the code for downloading. Playing should not be relevant as the songs are not fully downloaded.
